# seo with AngularJS in html5mode

Tags: angularjs, seo

I am trying to get my AngularJS with html5mode enabled indexed by google.

In my app.js I have the following snippet:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In my index.html `head` I have the following:

```
<base href="/"/>
<meta name="fragment" content="!"/>
```

I expected to get requests on urls of the format `/?_escaped_fragment_=support`. Instead I'm getting requests on `/support?_escaped_fragment_=`.

Is there something wrong with my config or did I expect something weird?

Answer (score 0):

according to the yearofmoo SEO article you should get this:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/some/page/with/ajax/content
```

[YearofMoo - SEO](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)